# Sort array by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have one array

```
$a = array(    0=>'test', 1=>'test some', 10=>'test10',
               2=>'test2', '11'=>'test value',22=>'test abc'
         );
```

I need to sort it like

```
0 => test
1 => test some
10 => test 10
11 => test value
2 => test2
22 => test abc
```

How can i able to do this?

I tried ksort but it not work as per my requirement

ksort result

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
    [10] => test10
    [11] => test11
    [22] => test22
)
```

Comment: Use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: If all the keys were strings like the key '11' ksort (with SORT_STRING flag) will work as you wanted.

Comment: @DavidLopez you should add answer :) you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$a = array(0=>'test', 1=>'test1', 10=>'test10', 2=>'test2', '11'=>'test11', 22=>'test22');
ksort($a, SORT_STRING);
print_r($a)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test1
    [10] => test10
    [11] => test11
    [2] => test2
    [22] => test22
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using uksort to get desired result .The uksort() function sorts an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function.

```
$a= array(    0=>'test', 1=>'test1', 10=>'test10',
               2=>'test2', '11'=>'test11',22=>'test22'
         );
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
if ($a==0) return 0;
return (substr($a, 0, 1)<substr($b, 0, 1))?-1:1;
}

uksort($a,"my_sort");
print_r($a);
```

**Output**

```
 Array ( [0] => test 
[1] => test1 
[10] => test10 
[11] => test11 
[2] => test2 
[22] => test22 )
```